# Schwarz-Pick on a disc of radius R > 0...

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $R, C > 0$. Let f be a holomorphic function defined on $D(0, R)$ and such that f is bounded above by $C$. Prove that

$$|f'(z)| \leq \frac{R}{C}\cdot \frac{C^2 - |f(z)|^2}{R^2 - |z|^2}.$$

I am honestly just confused by this problem. My initial attempt was to reverse engineer the proof for Schwarz-Pick but it did not work out. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you construct a related function which is holomorphic in the unit disk, and bounded (in magnitude) by one?

Comment: Ahhhhhh, thank you this helps.

Comment: So, I used $g(z) = \frac{C}{R}f(z)$, and I believe it worked.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it should be $g(z) = \frac 1C f(Rz)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is a holomorphic function from $D(0, R)$ into $ D(0, C)$, therefore
$$
 g(z) = \frac 1C f(Rz)
$$
is defined for $z \in \Bbb D$ (the unit disk) with values in $\Bbb D$, and we can apply the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem) to $g$:
$$ 
|g'(z)| \le \frac{1-|g(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}
$$
for all $z \in \Bbb D$. Now we transform this result back to $f$:
$$
 f(z) = C g(\frac zR) \, , \quad f'(z) = \frac CR g'(\frac zR) \, ,
$$
so that
$$
|f'(z)| = \frac CR | g'(\frac zR)| \le \frac CR \frac{1-|g(\frac zR)|^2}{1-|\frac zR|^2} = \ldots = \frac RC \frac{C^2 - |f(z)|^2}{R^2 - |z|^2} \, .
$$

Comment: This is correct, I realized my mistake after I posted that comment, thanks.